# Convert PHP array string into array

Tags: php, arrays

If i execute `var_dump(array($output))` is shows

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(573) " __(Developer’s Must Have Gray Cardigan|:89.77,gravityforms), __(Polka Dots Blue Dress|:55.45,gravityforms), __(Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:66.84,gravityforms), __(Cycling Pack Steel Blue|:360.00,gravityforms), __(Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:,gravityforms), __(The Black Cat Winter Jacket|:254.45,gravityforms), __(Split Slit Gold Threading Cardi|:165.74,gravityforms), __(Slim Fit Pants|:85,gravityforms), __(Get the Complete WordPress Developer Outfit|:65.55,gravityforms), __(Biodiesel Cardigan Dreamcatcher|:175.00,gravityforms)," }
```

But i want to like this

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(44) "Developer’s Must Have Gray Cardigan|:89.77" [1]=> string(28) "Polka Dots Blue Dress|:55.45" [2]=> string(52) "Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:66.84" [3]=> string(31) "Cycling Pack Steel Blue|:360.00" [4]=> string(47) "Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:" [5]=> string(35) "The Black Cat Winter Jacket|:254.45" [6]=> string(39) "Split Slit Gold Threading Cardi|:165.74" [7]=> string(18) "Slim Fit Pants|:85" [8]=> string(50) "Get the Complete WordPress Developer Outfit|:65.55" [9]=> string(39) "Biodiesel Cardigan Dreamcatcher|:175.00" }
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Just because something starts with the term `arrray` doesnt make it an array. That string does not have a valid PHP array syntax.

Comment: I suspect you're doing something funky somehow. What is your function `__()`, for instance? Without that, I can't even try to reproduce your code.

Comment: staticsan actually i want to customize gravity forms for that i need to use __() to work with their functionality

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_push`

```
$outputArr = array();
if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
        array_push($outputArr, ' __(' . get_the_title() . '|:' . $price . ',gravityforms)');
    }
}

var_dump($outputArr);
```

Hope this helps

If you want use this array further make `foreach` and execute

Comment: while you asking question please ask that elaborately, so others can easily understand. Please accept the answer once you got the expected solution for that question.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
$l = array(
    " __(Developer’s Must Have Gray Cardigan|:89.77,gravityforms), __(Polka Dots Blue Dress|:55.45,gravityforms), __(Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:66.84,gravityforms), __(Cycling Pack Steel Blue|:360.00,gravityforms), __(Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:,gravityforms), __(The Black Cat Winter Jacket|:254.45,gravityforms), __(Split Slit Gold Threading Cardi|:165.74,gravityforms), __(Slim Fit Pants|:85,gravityforms), __(Get the Complete WordPress Developer Outfit|:65.55,gravityforms), __(Biodiesel Cardigan Dreamcatcher|:175.00,gravityforms),"
);

$m = explode('__', $l[0]);
$n = array();

array_walk($m, function ($x, $y) use (&$n) {
    $w = trim(preg_replace('/,(|\s+)$/', '', $x));
    $n[] = ($w) ? '__'.$w : '';
});

$result = array_slice(array_filter($n), 0);

var_dump($result);
```

### Output

[image: OUTPUT]

### Edit

Or you can just use this

```
$l = array(
    " __(Developer’s Must Have Gray Cardigan|:89.77,gravityforms), __(Polka Dots Blue Dress|:55.45,gravityforms), __(Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:66.84,gravityforms), __(Cycling Pack Steel Blue|:360.00,gravityforms), __(Classic Brown Leather Bag with Orange Details|:,gravityforms), __(The Black Cat Winter Jacket|:254.45,gravityforms), __(Split Slit Gold Threading Cardi|:165.74,gravityforms), __(Slim Fit Pants|:85,gravityforms), __(Get the Complete WordPress Developer Outfit|:65.55,gravityforms), __(Biodiesel Cardigan Dreamcatcher|:175.00,gravityforms),"
);

$n = explode(', ', $l[0]);
```